# move to another tab while async request being sent ios

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I have an app with tabbarcontroller. As of now when an async request is being sent on one of the tabs, the user cannot move to another tab. I want my app to function such that when the request is being sent, user is able to move to other tabs and the async request stays is progress still timeout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how an asynchronous method can prevent a user to switch to another view. Please show your code.

Comment: can not or may not ? Is your request logic tied up with your view controller logic ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending an async request from a view controller, the user will be able to move to another tab. That's the default behaviour. So unless you have built in logic to change that behaviour (i.e. waiting for an async until it has finished). If that's the case, then you should obviously remove that logic.

If that's not the case i suspect you are currently sending a synchronous request (and not an async request as stated in the question). Sending a synchronous request from a view controller would result in the behaviour as described in your issue. So if that's the case, you should rewrite that and make it an async request.

And if you are still unsure, just post your code!